# Split first and last name with UTF-8 Chars in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hoping someone can help give a simple solution to splitting a first and last name when the full name has french or other accents on the characters.

This seems to work fine when when the name doesn't have any accents, but isn't working to detect the white space when there is an accent in the string.

An example name would be "Marc-André Côté"

```
$name = trim($FullNameInput);
$last_name = (strpos($name, ' ') === false) ? '' : preg_replace('#.*\s([\w-]*)$#', '$1', $name);
$first_name = trim( preg_replace('#'.$last_name.'#', '', $name ) );
```

Comment: Use `preg_replace('#.*\s([\w\'-]*)$#u', '$1', $name)`. A preg_match solution will be cleaner though: `preg_match('/\s([\w\'-]+)$/u', $name, $m)`.

Comment: Perfect! That fixed it!

Comment: Please also consider upvoting if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44291726/3832970) was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UNICODE modifier when dealing with Unicode strings and add a single quote since some names contain it:

```
 preg_replace('#.*\s([\w\'-]*)$#u', '$1', $name)
```

The UNICODE modifier will also make `\w`  Unicode aware. A `preg_match` solution will be cleaner though:

```
 preg_match('/\s\K[\w\'-]+$/u', $name, $m)
```

You just need to check if there is a match. If there is a match, get `$m[0]`, else assign an empty string to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode Function. It runs with your example name without any problems and it´s much easier than your regex solution

```
    $nameparts = explode(" ", $name);
    echo $nameparts[0]; // First Name
    echo $nameparts[1]; // Last Name
```